Flet app building error with libpythonbundle.so
The flet app runs smoothly on windows and by flet run --android but, there is no problem with splas screen but built apk does not render views.
home/kali/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip: error: '/tmp/flet_flutter_build_rIboqLfqYR/build/serious_python_android/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86_64/libpythonbundle.so': The file was not recognized as a valid object file
